# C - Multiprocessing Threads Implementation - Pointers problem

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

i just need to write a code to calculate a local max of an half of an array.. but there's some problem with ponters (?)
i see `segmentation fault` problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 10

struct args {
    int index;
    int a[n];
};

void * max_locale(void * parameters) {
    struct args * pp = parameters;
    int max = pp->a[0];
    int finalIndex = pp->index + n/2;
    
    for(int i=pp->index; i<finalIndex; i++) {
        if((pp->a[i]) > (pp->a[i+1])) {
            max = (pp->a[i]);
        }
    }
    return (void *)&max;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int array[n];
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    struct args thread1_args, thread2_args;
    
    printf("-beginning of program-\n");
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 101;
        printf("%d  ", array[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        thread1_args.a[i] = array[i];
        thread2_args.a[i] = array[i];
    }
    
    int * thread1_returnValue; 
    int * thread2_returnValue;
    
    thread2_args.index = 0;
    thread2_args.index = n/2;
    
    
    
    printf("\n Find MAX... \n");
    
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &max_locale, &thread1_args);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &max_locale, &thread2_args);
    
    pthread_join(thread1, (void **) & thread1_returnValue);
    pthread_join(thread2, (void **) & thread2_returnValue);
    
    printf("Max 1:%d Max 2:%d \n", *thread1_returnValue, *thread2_returnValue);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
-beginning of program-
98 28 73 5 10 100 23 63 25 60
 Find MAX...
zsh: segmentation fault ./15-4-23
```

i tried to return int with the void * function,
there's a lot easier if i can do it passing different arguments in `pthred_create` function

Comment: You set `thread2_args.index` twice, but you don't set `thread1_args.index` at all.  Presumably you wanted to set each once.  This is likely the source of your problem.

Comment: `n` should probably be `N` as that indicates it's a `#define`. `n` is implied to be some kind of variable, usually local. A better name would also help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues ...

1. In `max_locale`, `max` is local to the function, so it goes out-of-scope when the function returns. Returning a pointer to it is flagged by the compiler as "returning the address of a local variable"
2. `thread1_args.index` is *never* intialized. So, we have UB (undefined behavior). When the thread function is executed, `pp->index` will have a wild-and-crazy value that causes a segfault.
3. In `max_locale`, the loop will *not* find the max value [unless the array is presorted?].
4. `n` is non-descript. Better to use (e.g. `NARRAY`)
5. The number of threads is fixed at 2. Using `thread1_args` and `thread2_args` doesn't scale. For example, suppose we had 100 threads? The better way is to have an *array* of `struct args`.
6. We can/should expand `struct args` and put *all* data related to the given thread in there.
7. No need to do `&max_locale`. For a function, just the function name is the pointer so use `max_locale`.

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if 0
#define n 10
#else
#ifndef NARRAY
#define NARRAY  37
#endif
#endif

struct args {
    int index;                          // starting index into array
#if 0
    int a[n];
#else
    pthread_t thread;
    int tidx;                           // index into threads array
    int max;                            // max value calculated by
    void *ret;                          // place for return value
    int a[NARRAY];                      // data values
#endif
};

#if 1
#ifndef NTHREADS
#define NTHREADS    3                   // number of threads
#endif
#define NPER    (NARRAY / NTHREADS)     // number of array elements / thread
#endif

// loop through all thread control blocks
#define TSKFORALL(_pp) \
    struct args *_pp = &thread_args[0];  _pp < &thread_args[NTHREADS];  ++_pp

void *
max_locale(void *parameters)
{
    struct args *pp = parameters;
    int max = pp->a[0];
#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: if NARRAY not evenly divisible by NTHREADS, we must special case
// the last element
    int finalIndex = pp->index + NARRAY / 2;
#else
    int finalIndex = pp->index + NPER;
    if (pp->tidx == (NTHREADS - 1))
        finalIndex = NARRAY;
#endif

#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: this will _not_ get the max value for the segment
    for (int i = pp->index; i < finalIndex; i++) {
        if ((pp->a[i]) > (pp->a[i + 1])) {
            max = (pp->a[i]);
        }
    }
#else
    for (int i = pp->index; i < finalIndex; i++) {
        int cur = pp->a[i];
        if (cur > max)
            max = cur;
    }
#endif

#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: this is flagged by the compiler as returning a _local_ variable
    return (void *) &max;
#else
    pp->max = max;
    return (void *) &pp->max;
#endif
}

int
main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

#if 0
    int array[n];
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    struct args thread1_args, thread2_args;
#else
    int array[NARRAY];
    struct args thread_args[NTHREADS];
#endif

    printf("-beginning of program-\n");

    int totlen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NARRAY; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 101;
        totlen += printf(" %d", array[i]);
        if (totlen >= 70) {
            totlen = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < NARRAY; i++) {
        thread1_args.a[i] = array[i];
        thread2_args.a[i] = array[i];
    }
#else
    for (TSKFORALL(pp)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NARRAY; i++)
            pp->a[i] = array[i];
    }
#endif

#if 0
    int *thread1_returnValue;
    int *thread2_returnValue;
#endif

#if 0
    thread2_args.index = 0;
    thread2_args.index = n / 2;
#else
    for (TSKFORALL(pp)) {
        pp->tidx = pp - thread_args;
        pp->index = pp->tidx * NPER;
    }
#endif

    printf("\n Find MAX... \n");

#if 0
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &max_locale, &thread1_args);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &max_locale, &thread2_args);

    pthread_join(thread1, (void **) &thread1_returnValue);
    pthread_join(thread2, (void **) &thread2_returnValue);

    printf("Max 1:%d Max 2:%d \n", *thread1_returnValue, *thread2_returnValue);
#else
    for (TSKFORALL(pp))
        pthread_create(&pp->thread,NULL,max_locale,pp);

    for (TSKFORALL(pp))
        pthread_join(pp->thread,&pp->ret);

    for (TSKFORALL(pp))
        printf("Max %zd: %d\n",pp - thread_args,pp->max);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is some sample output:

```
-beginning of program-
 16 98 1 96 25 57 97 73 36 99 68 93 85 74 99 25 12 13 89 27 81 12 86 79
 8 27 64 35 5 29 89 22 26 90 84 18 12

 Find MAX...
Max 0: 99
Max 1: 99
Max 2: 90
```

---

Here is the cleaned up source (run through `unifdef -k`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef NARRAY
#define NARRAY  37
#endif

struct args {
    int index;                          // starting index into array
    pthread_t thread;
    int tidx;                           // index into threads array
    int max;                            // max value calculated by
    void *ret;                          // place for return value
    int a[NARRAY];                      // data values
};

#ifndef NTHREADS
#define NTHREADS    3                   // number of threads
#endif
#define NPER    (NARRAY / NTHREADS)     // number of array elements / thread

// loop through all thread control blocks
#define TSKFORALL(_pp) \
    struct args *_pp = &thread_args[0];  _pp < &thread_args[NTHREADS];  ++_pp

void *
max_locale(void *parameters)
{
    struct args *pp = parameters;
    int max = pp->a[0];
    int finalIndex = pp->index + NPER;
    if (pp->tidx == (NTHREADS - 1))
        finalIndex = NARRAY;

    for (int i = pp->index; i < finalIndex; i++) {
        int cur = pp->a[i];
        if (cur > max)
            max = cur;
    }

    pp->max = max;
    return (void *) &pp->max;
}

int
main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int array[NARRAY];
    struct args thread_args[NTHREADS];

    printf("-beginning of program-\n");

    int totlen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NARRAY; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 101;
        totlen += printf(" %d", array[i]);
        if (totlen >= 70) {
            totlen = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (TSKFORALL(pp)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NARRAY; i++)
            pp->a[i] = array[i];
    }

    for (TSKFORALL(pp)) {
        pp->tidx = pp - thread_args;
        pp->index = pp->tidx * NPER;
    }

    printf("\n Find MAX... \n");

    for (TSKFORALL(pp))
        pthread_create(&pp->thread,NULL,max_locale,pp);

    for (TSKFORALL(pp))
        pthread_join(pp->thread,&pp->ret);

    for (TSKFORALL(pp))
        printf("Max %zd: %d\n",pp - thread_args,pp->max);

    return 0;
}
```